# Where is the story of Ravana capturing all the 9 planets found?

Tags: scripture, hanuman, ravana, navagraha

There is a story of Ravana capturing all the 9 planets for the benefit of his son Meghanad.All the planets agree to go to the 11th house of his son but Lord Shani refuses and hence Ravana fights with Lord Shani and also captures the rest of the grahas.

Later Lord Hanuman rescues them.

Which scripture contains this story?
Is it a folklore?

Comment: Folklore, it is.

Comment: R u sure ? @Vivikta

Comment: Most probably @ShriRambhakt